# How to get started with ROS2 and UR5e using Python

Tags: python, ros, ros2, gazebo-simu

Looking to learn how to make a seam tracing algorithm using ROS2 (python dist) and a UR5e (ideally in Gazebo) and have been having a hard time coming across tutorials. Looking for any and all help as to where to look to get started.

Comment: Have you read through the official docs and tutorials for ROS2? They cover a lot of info and there are also Gazebo tutorials.